# just tried to install 20.04 in my xps 9380 dell and there are no devices found

Tags: boot, dell, 20.04, xps

I have a dell xps 9380 from work that came with 18.04 and today I tried to install a clean copy of 20.04.
i created a bootable usb stick and restarted BUT even though i can enter the boot menu and click the usb stick option under UEFI then i get the options "Ubuntu, Ubuntu(safe graphics), install manufacturer OEM" and then when i click to either Ubuntu or Ubuntu (safe graphics) the screen goes black and nothing is happening....
The other weird thing is that the usb stick option is shown twice (the second time it says partition 2 but there is no partition 2 in the usb stick....)

Having those problems with the UEFI i went to BIOS and switched the boot mode to legacy, I restarted and then tried to install which was succesful! the ubuntu screen came up and I installed normally but then after restarting I get the error 'no devices found'

Went back to BIOS and switched back to UEFI (since legacy does not support internal HDD) and tried to add a boot option manually BUT no boot option exists.... I click to "add boot option", select the hard drive but no directories and no files and no EFI and I am seriously seconds away before smashing that shitty laptop to pieces... I have installed ubuntu on HP, lenovo, mac etc etc this has never ever been so difficult

Any advice on how to solve this will be highly appreciated

Comment: In your Bios, your drives may be set to RAID. Change that to the other option (ACPI?, not sure). When my Dell was back from replacing a battery, I had to change that setting in order to be able to boot the existing installation.

Comment: no :( its already set to AHCI :(

Comment: OK, that is a specific problem with 20.04. I made a usb stick with the 18.04 and installed just fine through UEFI.